# What kind of data structure we should use to create map like Google map?

Tags: java, gis

If you had to indicate travel directions visually on a map (like say Google maps), what data structure would you use to store it? How would you store the map itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without putting much thought into it;

At the bare minimum, a geographical map is a set of vertices with edges connecting them, the vertices are intersections and dead ends of roads and the edges are the roads that connect them.

Directions are just a series of references to the vertices you need to traverse to get from vertex A to vertex B.

So to store a geographical map, you use a tree/map. To provide directions you use a list of references to vertices or the starting vertex and the list of edges to get to the end vertex.

Associating more information with each vertex/edge then gives you everything you need to make a full map. (IE, weight of each edge to get the shortest path).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about this particular domain, but I recently heard about [road XML](http://www.road-xml.org/), an open file format to describe road networks.

Maybe the format itself can give you an insight of how suh data can be represented.

Answer (score 1):

As far as external file formats, consider [GPX](http://www.topografix.com/gpx.asp); it's a well-known XML-based format with extensible schema.